# mandrill SMTP Intergration .net

Tags: c#, smtp, mandrill

I've mandrill paid account and I trying to use Mandrill SMTP services to send emails by using c#.net. But it is throwing an error "Host not found". I'm providing all the necessary information to service. The issue was unidentified yet.

Please find my code below and please suggest what are the necessary changes have to made to the code.

```
System.Net.Mail.MailMessage message = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage();

message.To.Add(toAddresses);
message.Subject = subject;
message.From = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress(from, from);

message.IsBodyHtml = true;
message.Body = body;
message.BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
message.Priority = System.Net.Mail.MailPriority.Normal;
smtp.Host = "smtp.mandrillapp.com";
smtp.EnableSsl = false;
smtp.DeliveryMethod = System.Net.Mail.SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(userName, password);
smtp.Port = 587;
smtp.Send(message);
```

Comment: Can you resolve & connect manually? `telnet smtp.mandrillapp.com 587`

Comment: no luck @alex..

Comment: It works fine for me, I get a banner `220 smtp.mandrillapp.com ESMTP` what error do you get? Can you resolive it? `nslookup smtp.mandrillapp.com`

Comment: @KiranMadhav It looks like your DNS server is not finding `smtp.mandrillapp.com` - try specifying one of the IP's (`52.7.100.156`, `52.6.223.177`, `52.7.167.198`, `54.152.96.156`) instead of the hostname, if it is resolved then you need to determine why the DNS lookup is failing. (Could be filtered by your ISP, et. al.)

Comment: @alex K&@EBrown, I've resolved the issue. nslookup not working on server, I used different server and get an ip address using nslookup, replaced with smtp.mandrillapp.com. Its working.